What is the difference between free product and direct sum?
This is a sentence I saw in Topology by Munkres."In this section, we study a concept that plays a role for arbitrary groups similar to
that played by the direct sum for abelian groups. It is called the free product of groups"
I am not able to understand what is the difference between them.Anyone please help me to clarify.

For example, the free product of two nontrivial finite groups is always infinite. On the other hand, the direct product of two finite groups is always finite.

In the free product of two groups, the two groups are not assumed to commute with each other. In particular, if the groups are commutative, the direct sum is commutative, but the free product is not. The free product of two finite groups can be infinite.

The free product is the coproduct in the category of groups. The direct sum is the coproduct in the category of abelian groups.

Your post is rather vague. What definition of free product are you not able to understand? Can you point to any specific item or items of that definition that are troublesome to your understanding? Adding things like this to your post will greatly improve it.

Let's say that we have two groups: $G=H=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. So these are finite groups of order $2$. Their direct sum $G\oplus H$ is their Cartesian product with pointwise group operation. In particular it is an abelian group of order $4$. If we write the direct sum in terms of presentation it will be
$$\langle a,b\ |\ a^2=b^2=1,\ ab=ba\}$$
Here $a$ stands for $(1+2\mathbb{Z},0)$ while $b$ for $(0,1+2\mathbb{Z})$.
However, their free product $G*H$ is quite complicated. Even though it has a simpler presentation:
$$\langle a,b\ |\ a^2=b^2=1\rangle$$
Note that there is no commutativity $ab=ba$ condition. In particular the free product is not abelian, unlike direct sum.
Moreover, it is not finite. Indeed, the following elements are all distinct:
$$a, ab, aba, abab,ababa,\ldots$$
...and so on. Unlike commutative case these do not reduce.
In fact, the free product of groups is never finite, unless one of them is trivial and the other is finite. And it is never abelian, unless one of the group is trivial and the other is abelian.
So in a sense, you can think about direct sum as free product with the additional commutativity condition. Sounds like a small difference but as we can see it has quite big impact on the result.
